# html 5 video tag file without extension

Tags: video, html

I have this sample code, that works:

```
<video src="./ellen.ogv" width="320" height="240" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' controls></video>
```

And this one that doesn't work:

```
<video src="./ellen" width="320" height="240" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' controls></video>
```

The only change was on the name of the file. First one "point" his extension, second one does not.
This is just a simple view of my problem, where the file I want to stream CAN'T have extension, but is a theora/vorbis (ogv) file.

How can I deal with this problem, i.e., make video tag works even if my filename doesn't have a ".extension" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the `type` attribute is not allowed on the video tag.  Place the `type` attribute in a `source` tag instead, like this:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="./ellen" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
</video>
```

Second, video files must be served with the proper MIME type by the web server, even when you have specified a `type` attribute in the `source` element.  Make sure that your web server serves your video files with `Content-Type: video/ogg` regardless of whether they have the `.ogv` extension or not.

Comment: är Would you know about zpt (zope page templates), to let me know how can I change the mimetype of the content file "on the fly" on there?

Comment: No, I haven't worked with Zope so I can't help you there, unfortunately.  Your best bet is probably to Google around for `zope content-type`, `zope mime-type` or similar, or to ask a separate question here regarding how to specify a content type for your video files.

Comment: @Gabriel. Note that even with the correct MIME type, the file extension may still matter. It shouldn't, but some browsers do look at file extensions. http://serverfault.com/questions/209753/do-file-extensions-matter-if-youre-sending-the-right-mime-type